# Jquery seems doesn't complete scroll function

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to replace header background color, color and logo image when user scroll page after a point.

It works correctly when I scroll down, but when I scroll to top it seems that jquery doesn't complete the function, sometimes it works correctly but sometimes I can see two logos one over another, and background color doesn't change, only text color changes correctly.

I tried to put a timeout in scroll function but it doesn't work..

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){

    var screenTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        if(screenTop > 55){
            if($(".menu").length > 0){


                $(".menu").css("background-color", $newbgcol);
                $(".menu").find("a").css("color", $newcol);
                $(".menu").find("span").css("color", $newcol);
                $("#menu_logo").find("img").attr("src",$newlogo);
            }
        }
        else{

            if($(".menu").length > 0){



                $(".menu").css("background-color", "");
                $(".menu").find("a").css("color", $oldcol);
                $(".menu").find("span").css("color", $oldcol);

                $(".menu").find(".sub-menu").find("a").css("color", $subtxtcol);
                $(".menu").find(".sub-menu").find("span").css("color", $subtxtcol);

                $("#menu_logo").find("img").attr("src",$oldlogo);
            }
        }

});
```

Comment: Not sure it's the problem, but are you aware that `.find` will find any element **at any level** under the parent node?  I'm only asking because you have `$(".menu").find("a")` and `$(".menu)".find(".sub-menu").find("a")`... the former will including items that are in the latter

Comment: Also, you don't need multiple `.find` as they just take normal CSS selectors... so you can have things like `.find(".sub-menu a, .sub-menu span")`.  And to be honest you don't even need the find with things like `$(".menu .sub-menu a, .menu .sub-menu span")`

Comment: Oh, and calling `$(".menu"` is pretty inefficient... every time you call it jQuery has to trawl the DOM to find all instances of that class.  You'd be better finding them once and storing them in a variable, then using the variable... `var $menu = $(".menu");  $menu.find(....);`

Comment: I've done all your edits but it still doesn't work @freefaller

Comment: Without an [mcve] in your question (preferably built using a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)) I cannot help